# I'm having trouble running a js script in debian with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, log4js-node

How I run the script:

> *node site.js*

The error I get :

> throw new Error(`Problem with log4js configuration:
>   (${util.inspect(this.candida depth: 5 })})` +
>           ^ Error: Problem with log4js configuration: ({ appenders:    [ { type: 'console' },
>        { type: 'file', filename: 'logs/site.log' } ] }) - must have a property "appenders"ype object.
>       at tests.forEach (/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.js:43:15)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Configuration.throwExceptionIf (/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.j11)
>       at new Configuration (/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/configuration.js:203:10)
>       at Object.configure (/home/bot/node_modules/log4js/lib/log4js.js:205:12)
>       at Object. (/home/bot/site.js:36:8)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:577:32)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)

I don't know what I should do to fix this, could someone please assist me?

Comment: Which "log4js" version is used?
Looks like the dame misconfiguration as the one described here - https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/issues/500

Comment: I figured it out! I had some outdated format with my appenders section! Thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to update my appenders section from version v1 to v2 inside my site.js files!